# What is /bin/[ in OS X for?

Tags: macos

I figured there's a "[" binary under my /bin/ that I'm really curious what it is about. In my case it's under Yosemite.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `man [`?

Comment: It implements `test`, as in `if [...`

Comment: thanks guys! this is very nice of you!